# jQuery isn't recognizing a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a click event to a button but it ain't working.

This is what I've got so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#btn_showComments").click(function() {
            alert("Hi from the button! :)");
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="#background">
   <div id="#showMoreComments">
      <button id="#btn_showComments">Show more comments!</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

I know it's kind of a silly question. But what am I doing wrong?

Comment: get rid of the "#" on your `div id="#btn_showComments">` div and it should work

Comment: As a rule of thumb, don't let your ids start with a hashtag. html is not twitter

Comment: @baao Some html is twitter lol

Comment: In the very off-chance that you can't modify the HTML, you *could* select the element by escaping the `#`, using `\\ `. The selector would be something like `$("#\\#btn_showComments")`. Though if you have control over the HTML, ignore this comment entirely ;)

Comment: Remove # in every ID attribute.

Comment: @baao "don't let your ids start with a **hash**" it's not called a hashtag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First remove the "#" from the id declaration in button tag i.e have this:

```
<button id="btn_showComments">Show more comments!</button>
```

Second, move the script below the html.

Comment: OMG! Why did I put that there? I'm so dumb. I didn't even realize. Hahahah thanks. :)

Comment: Never mind. Such things happen all the time. All the best. :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the # from the button id. The # tells JQuery to select an element with the following id.
Like this:

```
<div id="#background">
   <div id="#showMoreComments">
      <button id="btn_showComments">Show more comments!</button>
   </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#btn_showComments").click(function() {
            alert("Hi from the button! :)");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Exactly!! Try to post the reasons than a mere working code.

Answer (score 1):

```
<button id="#btn_showComments">Show more comments!</button>
```

should be -

```
<button id="btn_showComments">Show more comments!</button>
```

then your code will work just fine. :)

Kindly don't use `#` in HTML tags for IDs. `#` is attached to get an element using its ID.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `#` from the element in the html.

```
<div id="background">
   <div id="showMoreComments">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, actually you have added # in your html code for ids. Please remove it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#btn_showComments").click(function() {
            alert("Hi from the button! :)");
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="background">
   <div id="showMoreComments">
      <button id="btn_showComments">Show more comments!</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How is your answer any different from the four other ones?

Comment: Sir I agree with you but I reply a bit late.